# Could I use "dataWithContentsOfURL" with "HTTP POST"

Tags: ios

Currently, I'm using "dataWithContentsOfURL" to send data to server and I append the data to the URL as a HTTP GET request.

However, because some data lots of text, I would like to switch from HTTP GET to HTTP POST.

Hence, could I use dataWithContentsOfURL with HTTP POST. Any example?

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:concatenatedString];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url1];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You really *really* should switch over to using an asynchronous [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Absolutely.  Never use ___withContentsOfURL in a real app.

Comment: @jsd: Agreed, with one exception: it's perfectly fine for local `file://` URLs, e.g. things you get from `-[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]`. But horrid for anything remote.

Comment: Any reason to switch to NSURLConnection, other than I need to use POST. Notice the above code is asynchronous because its between  dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

Comment: @user836026: yes there are many reasons, even if you use dispatch_async. most important is being able to cancel. watch the "network apps for iOS" wwdc session videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=207

Comment: Even if you're using `dispatch_async()`, you're blocking an entire thread in your application for one synchronous network load. That's pretty bad. Just imagine if you had 10 of these things, now you're wasting 5MB (of stack) and 10 blocked threads just for network IO.